# How to display image from AWS s3 using spring boot and react?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, amazon-s3

How to display images from amazon s3 bucket in react?
Images are not being displayed using amazon s3,spring boot 2.5.3,react.

I have tested the end points in postman, it works.

React: Using Axios to connect to backend and MyDropZone

Using axios to make a post request, I can confirm that images are being saved in s3.
[image: Saved image]

This is the reponse after making a post request, for the first 2 user.

```
[
   {
      "userId":"565c6cbe-7833-482d-b0d4-2edcd7fc6163",
      "userName":"John",
      "imageUrl":"pexels-photo-3147528.jpeg"
   },
   {
      "userId":"3c776990-38e8-4de4-b7c6-7875c0ebb20f",
      "userName":"Anthony",
      "imageUrl":"pexels-photo-3147528.jpeg"
   },
   {
      "userId":"bcac9cf2-5508-4996-953e-b18afe866581",
      "userName":"Peter",
      "imageUrl":null
   }
]
```

React:

```
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState, useEffect,useCallback } from 'react';
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone'



//
const UserProfiles = () => {

  const [userProfiles,setUserProfiles]=useState([])

  const fetchUserProfiles=() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users').then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
      setUserProfiles(response.data)
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserProfiles();
  }, [])

  return userProfiles.map((profile,index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index}>
        <MyDropZone userId={profile.userId}></MyDropZone>
        <h3>{profile.userId}</h3>
        {
          profile.userId ? (<img src={`http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/${profile.userId}/image/download`} /> ) : <h5>No profile Image Uploaded</h5>
        }
      </div>
    );
  })
}

function MyDropZone({userId}) {
  const onDrop = useCallback(acceptedFiles => {
    // Do something with the files
    console.log(acceptedFiles[0])
    const file=acceptedFiles[0]
    //Form-data
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', file)
    
    //Make a post req
    axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/${userId}/image/upload`, formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
      }
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
      console.log("Uploaded")
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }, [])
  const {getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive} = useDropzone({onDrop})

  return (
    <div {...getRootProps()}>
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
      {
        isDragActive ?
          <p>Drop the files here ...</p> :
          <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
      }
    </div>
  )
}



function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UserProfiles ></UserProfiles>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The image is not being loaded in the UI.

```
{
 profile.userId ? (<img src={`http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/${profile.userId}/image/download`} /> ) : <h5>No profile Image Uploaded</h5>
}
```

[image: This is how it looks in the inspect element.]

When I go to this `http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/565c6cbe-7833-482d-b0d4-2edcd7fc6163/image/download` URL via browser.
It has a response with

```
 ÿØÿàJFIFHHÿâICC_PROFILElcmsmntrRGB XYZ Ü)9acspAPPLöÖÓ-lcms descü^cprt\wtpthbkpt|rXYZgXYZ¤bXYZ¸rTRCÌ@gTRCÌ@b
```

**Update Added Backend code.**

controller

```
@GetMapping(path = "{userId}/image/download")
public byte[] downloadUserProfileImage(@PathVariable("userId") UUID userId) {
    return userProfileService.downloadUserProfileImage(userId);
}
```

Service:

```
private UserProfile getUserProfileOrThrow(UUID userId) {
    UserProfile userProfile = userProfileRepository.getUserProfiles()
            .stream()
            .filter(profile -> profile.getUserId().equals(userId)).findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("User does not exist" + userId)
            );
    return userProfile;
}
public byte[] downloadUserProfileImage(UUID userId) {
    UserProfile userProfile=getUserProfileOrThrow(userId);
    String path = String.format("%s/%s",
            BucketName.PROFILE_IMAGE.getBucketName(),
            userProfile.getUserId());

    return userProfile.getImageUrl()
            .map(key -> fileStore.download(path, key))
            .orElse(new byte[0]);
}
```

FileStore:

```
@Service
public class FileStore {
    private final AmazonS3 s3;

@Autowired
public FileStore(AmazonS3 s3) {
    this.s3 = s3;
}
public void save(String path,
                 String fileName,
                 Optional<Map<String, String>> optionalMetadata,
                 InputStream inputStream) {
    ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();

    optionalMetadata.ifPresent(map -> {
        if (!map.isEmpty()) {
            map.forEach(metadata::addUserMetadata);
        }
    });

    try {
        s3.putObject(path, fileName, inputStream, metadata);
    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to store file to s3", e);
    }
}

public byte[] download(String path, String key) {
    try {
        S3Object object = s3.getObject(path, key);
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(object.getObjectContent());
    } catch (AmazonServiceException | IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to download file to s3", e);
    }
}
}
```

Amazon s3 config:
@Configuration
public class AmazonConfig {

```
@Bean
public AmazonS3 s3(){
    AWSCredentials  awsCredentials=new BasicAWSCredentials("my-credentials","my-secret-key");

    return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
            .withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1)
            .build();
}
```

}

UserProfile:

```
public class UserProfile {
    private final UUID userId;
    private final String userName;
    private String imageUrl;

    //This might be null
    public Optional<String> getImageUrl() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(imageUrl);
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
//getters & setters
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the backend code?

Comment: Can you update your download image endpoint to return a `Content-Type: 'image/jpeg'` response header.
You can do that using produces  `@GetMapping(path = "{userId}/image/download", produces = "image/jpeg")`

Comment: I have tried that. Did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was facing the same issue, I had to return the `object.getObjectContent()` image in a `Base64` format.

Afterwards, when displaying the data in the front-end, you can try and to this:

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

You can try [this Base64 decoder](https://www.opinionatedgeek.com/codecs/base64decoder) to see if your Base64 data is correct or not.

That implies that you make the GET call beforehand, save the result and then display the base64 string in the `img src`

UPDATE:

Depending on your approach, in order to download the images for each user profile, inside the `.map`, you can have a function that downloads the picture for each profile.

```js
  const fetchUserProfileImage = async (userProfileId) => {
    return axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/${profile.userId}/image/download`)

  }

  return userProfiles.map(async (profile,index) => {
    const userProfileImageBase64 = await fetchUserProfileImage(profile.userId)
    return (
      <div key={index}>
        <MyDropZone userId={profile.userId}></MyDropZone>
        <h3>{profile.userId}</h3>
        {
          profile.userId ? (<img src={`data:image/png;base64, ${userProfileImageBase64}`}/> ) : <h5>No profile Image Uploaded</h5>
        }
      </div>
    );
  })
```

Or if you don't like to wait inside the `.map`, you can try to download all of the images before rendering the body and mapping them to the already existing user in the `userProfiles` state.

Or, the best approach imo is to add another `profileImageSrc` field to the `User` class and save it there whenever you upload an image in the backend. Then you don't have to make extra calls and just consume the data received when fetching the `userProfiles`

Comment: I am already making a get call for the `userprofiles`. How do i make a get call to the user profile images after they are mapped from the userprofile list.

Comment: I have updated my answer, check it out, let me know if it helps

Comment: `fetchUserProfileImage` I needed this to the call and convert the response into something like this. `const base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(data)));` and then reload the page. It wroked.

Comment: why do this? for every request you would need to call the backend API just to get the image. why not make the s3 bucket public access and then store the link in your database to that image of s3 bucket? that way you can just use the link URL (that links to s3 bucket where the image is stored) on the frontend to display the image. this way you do NOT need to call the backend every time just to get the image. you can just use the link to access the image whenever you want

Comment: I have 0 recollection why I've used that in my code 3 years ago tbh

Answer (score 0):

The simplest trick is to transform your byte arrays into an actual image

```
@GetMapping(path ="/download/{fileName}")
public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> downloadFile(@PathVariable String fileName) {
    byte[] data = service.downloadImage(fileName);
    ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(data);
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .contentLength(data.length)
            .header("Content-type", "image/jpeg")
            .header("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
            .body(resource);
}
```

This will return an actual image whether the image was jpg or png it will not matter. You can actually view the image in postman and your frontend can pick it up directly.